# Too much recursion on simple JS slider

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a simple slider by changing the background image, but i am not sure why I am getting an error that says too much recursion.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

let headerImages = [];
let header = document.querySelector('.header');
let i = 0;
let time = 3000;

headerImages[0] = 'img/header1.jpg';
headerImages[1] = 'img/header2.jpg';


function changeHeaderImg() {
    header.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + headerImages[i] + ")";

    if(i < headerImages.length - 1){
        i++;
    } else {
        i = 0;
    }

    setTimeout(changeHeaderImg(), time);
}

changeHeaderImg();



});
```

Comment: `setTimeout` expects the first argument to be a function, not the result of calling said function.

Comment: This site is exactly the one you need to solve such problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `changeHeaderImg` and passing it's result to `setTimeout` instead of passing `changeHeaderImg` itself.

So you are getting endless recursion which results in so-called "stack overflow" classic error.

Try `setTimeout(changeHeaderImg, time);`

Answer (score 1):

A function that calls itself is called a recursive function. Once a condition is met, the function stops calling itself. This is called a base case.

In some ways, recursion is analogous to a loop. Both execute the same code multiple times, and both require a condition (to avoid an infinite loop, or rather, infinite recursion in this case). When there are too many function calls, or a function is missing a base case, JavaScript will throw this error.

```
function loop(x) {
  if (x >= 10) // "x >= 10" is the exit condition
    return;
  // do stuff
  loop(x + 1); // the recursive call
}
loop(0);
```

Setting this condition to an extremely high value, won't work:

```
function loop(x) {
  if (x >= 1000000000000)
    return;
  // do stuff
  loop(x + 1);
}
loop(0);
// InternalError: too much recursion
```

This recursive function is missing a base case. As there is no exit condition, the function will call itself infinitely.

```
function loop(x) {
 // The base case is missinng
loop(x + 1); // Recursive call
}
loop(0);
// InternalError: too much recursion
```